# How do I extract difficulty and discrimination from a non-parametric IRT model

Tags: r, nonparametric, item-response-theory

I've been using the `KernSmoothIRT` module in R to do non-parametric analysis of some items.

I'm trying to find a way to quantify the difficulty and discrimination of a particular set of items.  What is the best way to do this with this module?

Geometrically, I think I'm looking for the value of OCC at theta=0 and the slope at P(theta)=0.5, but I'm not sure how to figure this out from what's generated by the library.

Comment: Bonus question: what's the best way to determine if the ICC is monotonically increasing?